# Symbol look up in an position independent so file

Tags: c, elf, symbols, dynamic-loading

I am writing a code to find a symbol within an ELF file.
In my code I open an ELF file, map all the segments to memory and store all the information related to various section and tables in a structure like this.

```
typedef struct Struct_Obj_Entry{

    //Name of the file
    const char          *filepath;

    //File pointer
    void*               ELF_fp;

    //Metadata of ELF header and  Progam header tables
    Elf32_Ehdr*         Ehdr;
    Elf32_Phdr*         Phdr_array;

    //base address of mapped region
    uint32               mapbase;

    //DYNAMIC Segment
    uint32              *dynamic;

    //DT_SYMTAB
    Elf32_Sym           *symtab; //Ptr to DT_SYMTAB

    //DT_STRTAB
    char                *strtab;

    //DT_HASH
    uint32              *hashtab;//Ptr to DT_HASH

    //Hash table variables
    int                 nbuckets, nchains;

    uint32              *buckets,
                    *chains;



} Obj_Entry;
```

This portion works perfectly fine and all the struct elements are correctly populated holding valid addresses to the regions of mapped ELF file.

Here is how I search for a symbol name,

```
void *return_symbol_vaddr(Obj_Entry  *obj, const char *name){

        unsigned long       hash_value;
        uint32              y=0,z=0;



        /*following part is DLSYM code to locate a symbol in a given file*/
        //Lets query for a symbol name
        hash_value = elf_Hash(name);

        printf("hash value =%lu\n",hash_value);

        //See if correct symbol entry found in bucket list
        //If it is break out
        y = (obj->buckets[hash_value % obj->nbuckets]);

        if((!strcmp(name, obj->strtab + obj->symtab[z].st_name))) {

                return (void*)(obj->mapbase + (obj->symtab[z]).st_value);
        }

        //If not there is a collision
        else{

                while(obj->chains[y] !=0){

                z = obj->chains[y];


            if((!strcmp(name, obj->strtab + obj->symtab[z].st_name))) {

                //return (void*)(obj->symtab[z].st_value);
                return (void*)(obj->mapbase + obj->symtab[z].st_value);
            }
            else{

                //If the symbol is not found in chains
                //There is double collision
                //In that case chain[y] gives the next symbol table entry with the same hash value
                y = z;

            }

        }


    }
```

}

The string hash function is a standard ABI specification:

```
//Get hash value for a symbol name
unsigned long
elf_Hash(const unsigned char *name)
{
    unsigned long h = 0, g;

        while (*name)
        {
             h = (h << 4) + *name++;
             if (g = h & 0xf0000000)
                  h ^= g >> 24;
                   h &= ~g;
        }
        return h;
}
```

Now the problem is when I compile a position independent so file and try to look for symbols. I am able to find some of the symbol and for rest of them the function returns NULL value.

Example ELF file

```
typedef struct _data{

    int x;
    int y;


}data;


int add(void){

    return 1;

}

int sub(void){

    return 4;

}

data Data ={3, 2};
```

When I compile this file to an ELF I can find add, Data symbols but surprisingly enough I cant find 'sub'. When I do a readelf on the .so file I can see that sub appears in DT_SYMTAB list of dynamic symbols.

Anybody can pin-point to a code bug?
Here is a link to how symbols are packed in an so
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-0690/chapter6-48031/index.html

Comment: I found out my error:
y = (obj->buckets[hash_value % obj->nbuckets]);

        if((!strcmp(name, obj->strtab + obj->symtab[z].st_name)))

obj->symtab[z] is supposed to be obj->symtab[y]